# Show that $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n}$ diverges

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation

In an old exam there was the exercise to show whether
$\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n}$
converges or not.
Wolframalpha told me, that it diverges, but how can I show it?
The root test gives me $1$, so it does not help.

Comment: Remember that the general term of a convergent series needs to converge to $0$...

Comment: If a series of complex numbers converges $\sum c_n$, then $|c_n|\to0$.

Comment: Another method ... this is a geometric series, so use formulas relevant to that.

Comment: @GEdgar not possible since $\mid \mathrm{e}^\mathrm{i}\mid = 1$.

Comment: @BobbyOcean I wonderful, thank you. That should do it. But this is not absolute convergence, right? How is the name of this property?

Comment: There is a nice formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, then investigate whether the partial sums of our series converge or not.

Comment: @BobbyOcean If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @Lereu In general, if a series converges, it's partial sums are a convergent sequence. Every convergent sequence is cauchy sequence, meaning that the terms get arbitrarily close to each other. Hence if $\sum c_n$ converges it must be that $c_n \to 0$. The fact that $c_n \to 0$ implies that $|c_n|\to 0$ is because "absolute value" is a continuous function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a series of complex numbers converges $\sum c_n$, then it must be that $|c_n|\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is
to look at the partial sums.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} e^{in}
&=\dfrac{1-e^{im}}{1-e^i}\\
&=\dfrac{1-(\cos(m)+i\sin(m))}{1-(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))}\\
\end{array}
$

and the numerator does not converge
so the sums do not converge.